# How to create POJO class for XML parsing using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, xml, retrofit2, pojo

I am integrating eBay in one of my project where XML parsing is needed. I am using Retrofit for XML parsing.

Here is that XML that I need to post

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetSessionIDRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RuName>abcxyzruname</RuName>
</GetSessionIDRequest>
```

To post this XML in retrofit I have followed [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-integrate-xml-converter) and created this class

```
@Root(name = "GetSessionIDRequest", strict = false)
public class GetSessionIDRequest {

    @Element(name = "RuName")
    private String RuName;

    @Attribute(required = false)
    private String xmlns;


    public GetSessionIDRequest(String ruName, String Xmlns) {
        RuName = ruName;
        xmlns = Xmlns;
    }
}
```

But I am missing this XMLProlog `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` while posting and just able to post this

```
<GetSessionIDRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RuName>abcxyzruname</RuName>
</GetSessionIDRequest>
```

Can anyone tell me how do I post XMLProLog so that I can get the proper response?

Comment: `Retrofit ` has nothing to do with parsing, it only does network requests.

Answer (score -1):

You did not create any field for `xml version` and `encoding` in your POJO class. Try to create those to fields.

Comment: How to create this?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
The above declaration has to be added outside the root element. So including them in the POJO class won't work.